# Updating a website often

Tags: web-development

I always wondered something, when I make a website, normally small websites, I make the website locally and then Upload it to the server, I also keep a copy locally, when I have to make a change, I change the copy I have locally and the I upload the whole website again to the server, that's obviously a waste of time, and I would like to know what's the best way to update a website, big or small, but without doing this, just uploading what has been changed, I've heard that the best way is using something like GIT or Mercurial, but I don't know what you can tell me.

Comment: Sorry but this question is too board and opinionated. To avoid further disappointment ensure you visit our [help center](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you upload the entire website? If you're changing one page, why not upload the page/resources in question?

With Git, etc, you're still uploading per se. i.e. I don't think that pushing content to your site with Git is going to be any faster than uploading changes via FTP.

Obviously, there are other benefits to Git and some of the other version control systems - However, I don't think that "speed-of-updating" is one of them. Still, that shouldn't stop you from using them, as they have a host of other benefits that are **essential** to any developer.

Comment: I know is a waste of time to upload the entire website, but that's why I ask this, because sometimes is hard to remember what I added to the website to upload only those files.